# exception in camera application in android

Tags: android

I am getting an exception using a custom front camera. On button click I am calling `camera.takepicture`. Can anybody tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

```
 09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949): java.lang.RuntimeException: Method called after release()
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:746)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at com.camera.test.CameraActivity.onClick(CameraActivity.java:42)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-23 11:24:35.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(949):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-23 11:24:35.082: WARN/ActivityManager(107):   Force finishing activity com.camera.test/.CameraActivity
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:configChanges="orientation">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1">
        </Button>
        <com.camera.test.Preview
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/preview" android:layout_marginTop="100px"/>   
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

my code

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Preview p=null;
    private Button button1=null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Hide the window title.
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        p=(Preview)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);   
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        //p.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        p.mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, jpegCallback);  

  /*    p.mCamera.(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() 
        {  
            Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback()
            {  
                public void onShutter() 
                {       // Play your sound here.    
                    }  
                };  
                public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera)
                {     
                    p.mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, jpegCallback); 
                    } 
                });*/
                }


        /*p.mCamera.startPreview();
        p.mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, jpegCallback); 
*/
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*p.mCamera.autoFocus(new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() 
        {  
            Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() 
            {     public void onShutter()
            {       
                // Play your sound here.    
            }   
            };  
            public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera)
            {    



            }
            });  */ 


     Camera.ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new Camera.ShutterCallback() { // <6>
            public void onShutter() {
                //Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
            }
        };

        //Handles data for raw picture
        Camera.PictureCallback rawCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() { // <7>
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
               // Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
            }
        };


        // Handles data for jpeg picture
        Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() { // <8>
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                 //YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(),  size.width, size.height, null); 

                //decodeYUV(argb8888, data, camSize.width, camSize.height);
                //Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(argb8888, camSize.width,                     
                        //camSize.height, Config.ARGB_8888); 
              // p.mCamera.startPreview();
                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Writing a  file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/Vijay");


                  dir.mkdir();


                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, dir.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //dir.mkdirs();
                //Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this,"%d.jpg"System.currentTimeMillis()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                File out = new File(dir,String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                try {


                    out.createNewFile();
                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "created new file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, out.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                DataOutputStream fo = null;

                    try {
                        fo = new DataOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(out));
                        //write what you want to fo
                        fo.write(data);
                        fo.close();
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                         Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "entering exception",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        PrintWriter pw;
                        try
                        {
                            File sdCard1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            File dir1 = new File(sdCard1.getAbsolutePath()+"/Log");


                               dir1.mkdir();

                           File out1 = new File(dir1,String.format("%d.txt", System.currentTimeMillis()));



                                try {
                                    out1.createNewFile();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }

                            pw = new PrintWriter(out1);
                            e.printStackTrace(pw); 

                        } 
                        catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                           //

                        }      
                            // TODO: handle exception

                        //e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //camera.release();



            }
        };


}
```

this is my preview

```
 package com.camera.test;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

     Camera mCamera;
    private final SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    final static int SUPPORTED_WIDTH = 640;
    final static int SUPPORTED_HEIGHT = 480;

    public Preview(Context context, AttributeSet attributes) {
        super(context, attributes);
        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    /**
     * Works in API level >= 10.
     *
     * @return Front camera handle.
     */
    Camera getFrontFacingCamera() throws NoSuchElementException 
    {
        final Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        for (int cameraIndex = 0; cameraIndex < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); cameraIndex++) 
        {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraIndex, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            {
                try {
                    return Camera.open(cameraIndex);
                } catch (final RuntimeException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Can't find front camera.");
    }

    /**
     * Works in API level >= 7 at Samsung Galaxy S.
     *
     * @param Camera handle.
     */
    void setFrontCamera(Camera camera) {
        final Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.set("camera-id", 2);
        try {
            camera.setParameters(parameters);
        } catch (final RuntimeException e) {
            // If we can't set front camera it means that device hasn't got "camera-id". Maybe it's not Galaxy S.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceChanged(android.view.SurfaceHolder, int, int, int)
     */
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin the preview.
        final Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        parameters.setPreviewSize(SUPPORTED_WIDTH, SUPPORTED_HEIGHT);
        mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    }

    /**
     * The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to draw.
     * 
     * @see android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceCreated(android.view.SurfaceHolder)
     */
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10) {
            mCamera = getFrontFacingCamera();
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        } else {
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            setFrontCamera(mCamera);
        }
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            //mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null); 
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback#surfaceDestroyed(android.view.SurfaceHolder)
     */
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        //mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null); 
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: @userSeven7s i posted my code

Comment: Have you given the permission in the AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncomment the line `mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);` in `public void  surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)` callback.